# Download US census files from the web using R

Tags: r, https, download

I am trying to download all 1980 US Census files from the URL https://www2.census.gov/census_1980/ and store in my computer using R.
I already tried `download.file` and the package `downloader`, but the usual commands download only one file with no format.
Is there an easy way to download all files (including subfolders, etc) at once in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if data you are interested in are in FRED | U.S. Census Bureau https://fred.stlouisfed.org/source?soid=19

If you are interested in somethin specific it is easy to get data with

```
# install.packages(quantmod)
library(quantmod)
retail_sales_total <- getSymbols('MRTSSM44X72USS', src = 'FRED', auto.assign = FALSE)
```

But if you want to get all files it is possible using xml2 and rvest packages.

```
# Readhtml
page <- read_html(URL)
#  Try to extract the atributes of the html and get all the download links
links <- html_attr(html_nodes(page, "a"), "href")
```

and download it all in a loop